# Do animal mobs tend to stick in a pack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What is the behavior of animal mobs in a pack?

Do they tend to stick around the area, or do they migrate?
Do some members leave the pack? Or do all of them stick together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no implementation of pack behavior, in either animals or monsters. However, wolves spawn in packs of 1 to 8 https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wolf.

Answer (score 1):

They only wander (each animal randomly, not a as a pack) when you are around. Each follows a given KI, which might be interpreted as pack behavior. Animals prefer gras and light. For more information see the following:

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Animal

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob_AI